# How can I separate a .json file by keys stored in a different .json file?

Tags: python, json, annotations

I have two files, one containing this type of data:

```
{"v_uqiMw7tQ1Cc": {"duration": 55.15, "timestamps": [[0.28, 55.15], [13.79, 54.32]]}, "v_bXdq2zI1Ms0": {"duration": 73.1, "timestamps": [[0, 10.23], [10.6, 39.84], [38.01, 73.1]]}
```

and the other file contains the splits ids:

```
{train_set:{"v_uqiMw7tQ1Cc","v_uqiMfergQ1Cc"}, test_set:{"v_bXdq2zI1Ms0", "v_bXdfreht2Ms0"}}
```

How do I change the first file for it to have the subset it belongs to?:

```
{"v_uqiMw7tQ1Cc": {"duration": 55.15, subset: "train", "timestamps": [[0.28, 55.15], [13.79, 54.32]]}, "v_bXdq2zI1Ms0": {"duration": 73.1, subset: "test", "timestamps": [[0, 10.23], [10.6, 39.84], [38.01, 73.1]]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code, I guess this is what you are looking for

```
import json

with open('json_file/json_set1.json') as f1:
    file1 = json.load(f1)
with open('json_file/json_set2.json') as f2:
    file2 = json.load(f2)

print(file1)
```

> {'v_uqiMw7tQ1Cc': {'duration': 55.15, 'timestamps': [[0.28, 55.15],
> [13.79, 54.32]]}, 'v_bXdq2zI1Ms0': {'duration': 73.1, 'timestamps':
> [[0, 10.23], [10.6, 39.84], [38.01, 73.1]]}}

```
print(file2)
```

> {'train_set': ['v_uqiMw7tQ1Cc', 'v_uqiMfergQ1Cc'], 'test_set':
> ['v_bXdq2zI1Ms0', 'v_bXdfreht2Ms0']}

```
for key1, val2 in file1.items():
    for key2, val2 in file2.items():
        if key1 in file2[key2]:
            file1[key1].update({'subset': key2})

print(file1)
```

> {'v_uqiMw7tQ1Cc': {'duration': 55.15, 'timestamps': [[0.28, 55.15],
> [13.79, 54.32]], 'subset': 'train_set'},

> 'v_bXdq2zI1Ms0': {'duration':
> 73.1, 'timestamps': [[0, 10.23], [10.6, 39.84], [38.01, 73.1]], 'subset': 'test_set'}}